# Collection.class.isAssignableFrom() with Type in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a method which lets me know if a `Type` is a collection.

```
public boolean isCollection(final Type type)
{
  final Type resolvedType;
  resolvedType = type() instanceof ParameterizedType ?
                   ((ParameterizedType)typeRef.getType()).getRawType() :
                   typeRef.getType();
  try
  {
    return Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(Class.forName(type.getTypeName()));
  }
  catch (final ClassNotFoundException cnfe)
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

However on porting this to Android I've found that it does not have `Type.getTypeName()` as this was introduced in Java 8.  Is there an equivalent to the above code which will run on Android?

Comment: I don't suppose the code that calls this has access to an instance of the type in question, or the corresponding Class object?

Comment: 'fraid not, would be easy if it did.